# How to use Link to wrap div in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<Link to="/promospace/detail">
    <div className="card">
        /* content */
    </div>
</Link>
```

I can't do above, no error but it just doesn't work. Any clue how to wrap div within Link? Or I have to bind it to a click handler? Can't use Link in jsx?

Comment: why you dont use from another tag?! like `span`

Comment: @AlirezaValizade a card should be a `div`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a span inside your link, and set `display: block` on it as well, that will definitely work everywhere, and it will validate!

```
<Link to="/promospace/detail">
    <span className="card" style={{"display": "block"}}>
        /* content */
    </span>
</Link>
```

Or else you can do dynamic routing on an onClick event

```
changeRoute = () => {
    this.context.router.push('/promospace/detail');
}
......
<div className="card" onClick={this.changeRoute}>
        /* content */
</div>

....
MyComponent.contextTypes = {
     router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the following functionality was available at the time you asked this question, but I was also wondering how to make a div navigate somewhere upon click

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const navigate = useNavigate();

<div className="card" onClick={() => navigate('/promospace/detail')}>
    /* content */
</div>
```